# Graphing data with the month as indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm struggling to find a solution in which I'll output a bar graph with the columns grouped together by month and labeled by the PN column for this dataframe.

Grouped

```
            EXT_PRICE            PN
 ENTRY_DATE                         
2017-12-12        0.0     3800702-1
2017-12-21        0.0     3800702-1
2017-12-26   585000.0     3800702-1
2018-01-10   225000.0   737-0010-25
2018-01-16    85000.0     2206400-2
2018-01-17    75000.0    173A0103-5
2018-01-17   565000.0     3800702-1
2018-01-29   565000.0     3800702-1
2018-02-08   150000.0    314-2100-2
2018-02-14   565000.0     3800702-1
2018-02-23   565000.0     3800702-1
2018-02-27   150000.0  737-0010-322
2018-02-28   565000.0     3800702-1
2018-03-05   565000.0     3800702-1
2018-03-06   580000.0     3800702-1
2018-03-12   565000.0     3800702-1
2018-03-13   580000.0     3800702-1
2018-03-22   650000.0     3800702-1
2018-04-03   115000.0    314-2100-2
2018-04-06   585000.0     3800702-1
2018-04-18    80000.0    HG2050AC07
2018-04-19   585000.0     3800702-1
2018-04-19   599900.0     3800702-1
2018-05-03    75000.0   1152426-245
2018-05-22   595000.0     3800702-1
2018-05-23   520000.0     3800702-1
2018-05-25   500000.0     3800702-1
2018-05-25   510000.0     3800702-1
2018-06-07   475000.0     3800702-1
2018-06-07   475000.0     3800702-1
2018-06-15   500000.0     3800702-1
2018-06-19   475000.0     3800702-1
2018-06-21   185000.0  822-1567-102
2018-07-02   185000.0  822-1567-102
2018-07-06   167000.0  822-1567-102
2018-07-09   174000.0  822-1567-102
2018-07-09   475000.0     3800702-1
2018-07-17   475000.0     3800702-1
2018-08-06   500000.0     3800702-1
2018-08-13   115000.0   251A4510-12
2018-08-15   500000.0     3800702-1
2018-08-22   115000.0   251A4510-12
2018-08-23   150000.0   737-0010-25
2018-09-04   150000.0   737-0010-25
2018-09-07   500000.0     3800702-1
2018-09-10   500000.0     3800702-1
2018-09-19   500000.0     3800702-1
2018-09-24   480000.0     3800702-1
2018-10-01   115000.0   251A4510-12
2018-10-01   110000.0    314-2100-2
2018-10-01   120000.0    314-2100-2
2018-10-04   115000.0   251A4510-12
2018-10-19    69000.0   1152426-245
```

Is there any way to do this?

```
df = pd.read_csv("PO25474.csv", encoding = 'Latin-1')

quotes['ENTRY_DATE'] = quotes['ENTRY_DATE'].astype('datetime64')
quotes['EXT_PRICE'] = quotes['EXT_PRICE'].apply(convert_currency)
quotes = quotes.set_index(['ENTRY_DATE'])
grouped = quotes[[ 'EXT_PRICE', 'PN']].sort_values(['EXT_PRICE'], ascending=False).groupby(lambda x: x.month).head(5)

grouped = grouped.sort_index()

plt.figure()
grouped.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

So far all I get is individual columns all in order by date but I'd like to group them together by month and with the Pn column labeling each column. So far it won't run at all.

EDIT: I believe a clustered bar chart is the terminology for what I'm hoping to spit out but still failing.

[Current Graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Losy6.png)

This is what I get currently, I'd like them to group together by month.

Comment: What do you want to do after grouping? like aggregate.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa I would like to plot them with the price column alongside each other to compare over each month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

men_means, men_std = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27), (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
women_means, women_std = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25), (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)

ind = np.arange(len(men_means))  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind - width/2, men_means, width, yerr=men_std,
                color='SkyBlue', label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width/2, women_means, width, yerr=women_std,
                color='IndianRed', label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects, xpos='center'):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height.

    *xpos* indicates which side to place the text w.r.t. the center of
    the bar. It can be one of the following {'center', 'right', 'left'}.
    """

    xpos = xpos.lower()  # normalize the case of the parameter
    ha = {'center': 'center', 'right': 'left', 'left': 'right'}
    offset = {'center': 0.5, 'right': 0.57, 'left': 0.43}  # x_txt = x + w*off

    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()*offset[xpos], 1.01*height,
                '{}'.format(height), ha=ha[xpos], va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1, "left")
autolabel(rects2, "right")

plt.show()
```

Read matplotlib documentaton
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py

Comment: Thanks @MalikAsad but I'm hoping to do it so that it automates itself and doesn't require me inputting the labels manually each time